# SPListItemVersionCollection - iteration performance

Tags: development, splistitem

This question is related to my issue described here: [SharePoint 2010 Performance troubleshooting](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41253/sharepoint-2010-performance-troubleshooting)

On SP 2010: Does anyone knows if there is some performance limitations while using [SPListItemVersionCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemversioncollection.aspx)?

Scenario: List with 3-4K items with unique item permissions and many versions (~5-60 per item).

When executing:

```
 foreach (SPListItemVersion version in spItem.Versions){...}
```

It takes just too long...

This code was used in `IHttpModule` so maybe this is reason why it takes too long but I am wondering if there is some general issue with `SPListItemVersionCollection` that I am not aware of.

Comment: Sorry to break your tumbleweed record, but did you ever find an answer to this? I am experiencing the same problem.

Comment: You can limit the fields you're getting by using the workaround: http://slavensemper.blogspot.com/2013/12/splistitem-with-too-many.html

Comment: Please provide more than a link as an answer. If the link breaks, your answer will be of very little help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of placing the  spItem.Versions in foreach statement. out the versions in a variable.

```
var versions =  spItem.Versions;
foreach(var item in versions) {}
```

because whenever you call spItem.Versions, SharePoint will make a call to get all the versions.

Comment: This is not right, the compiler get the enumerator and iterates that, it does not call the property `.Versions` each time. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19867119/681538