# SharePoint 2013 poor performance

Tags: 2013, performance

I have a vanilla SharePoint 2013 server virtualized under Hyper-V for a dev environment. Both application server and database server have 12 GB of RAM and 4 core CPU. All services are enabled, search crawling paused.

I can see my SQL server under a heavy load even when no requests is made, the process is taking about 20-30%. Whenever I request a page this goes up to between 60-80% and it takes roughly 6 seconds for any pages to come up. When I created my first site collection after running the installation wizard it timed out twice on me, and took 13 minutes the third time to succeed.

If I check the recommended specs for a dev environment, my setup is largely above it. What is wrong? How can I speed that up to something respectable?

Comment: How is your host running the Hyper-V instance configured? OS, RAM, Disk size/type, CPU etc?

Comment: @Benny Skogberg The host use 4 servers with 8 processors each. Storage is a SAN of hard disk arrays wich make up += 32 tera. Ram I dont know how much total, I havent mounted the host myself may be around 256 GB. There's more than 2 virtualized machines in there. My VM network for Sharepoint uses 1 NUMA block of 64 GB (including both app server, data, dc, 1 dev machine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWI:

The problem was that the ram was allocated dynamically on the VMS. You must set it static to have a good performance.

Answer (score 4):

MS suggests 24gb for a dev environment with all services running (10gb for minimal services with Visual Studio)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx#hwforwebserver

Answer (score 1):

I experience performance issues with anything less that 16GB of RAM for my SP2013 development environments.  32GB would be even better if you have it.

I have also noticed better performance (and this is the case with most Windows services running under Hyper-V) when I use only 1 CPU core (or possibly 2).  Anything over that results in degraded performance in my experience.

Comment: Microsoft does have some guidance for using SharePoint 2013 in Hyper-V.  It doesn't specifically apply to development environments, but could prove useful: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ff621103(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Also, the MS documentation on creating a development environment indicates 16GB would be the minimum: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx

Comment: This is for a standalone installation, my app server and data server are separated on 2 machines which makes up a total of 24 GB

Comment: For your environment, you don't have to set the max ram at 12GB for both.  You can set both to dynamically use 4GB to 24GB and let Hyper-V handle how much RAM each is allotted to each environment.

Comment: The startup is at 12 GB, Max 14 GB for both. I can try to let them scale and see how it goes

Answer (score 0):

In my dev environment I have a VirtualBox VM with 16G of RAM for SharePoint 2013.  Since my host OS has 32G of RAM I could go up a little, but sometimes am running my SP2010 VM at the same time.  Regardless, my problem seems to be that it is more CPU bound.  Since mine is a dev environment and I am not using Workflow (currently), I just kill Microsoft.Workflow.ServiceHost from the task manager.  I'm sure this has negative side effects, but the positive side effect is that my CPU goes from 100% to below 70% (until an incremental crawl starts :-).  Sometime I need to figure out how to throttle workflow better, but maybe this approach will help for you.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a couple of blog posts on why SharePoint Installations are typically slow. Most of the time its caused by SharePoint developers assuming SharePoint is a very flexible database and you can put any type of information in there. People dont understand that everything will be stored in a single table. Here is a blog you hopefully find useful: [Top SharePoint Performance Problems](http://apmblog.compuware.com/2010/03/18/how-to-avoid-the-top-5-sharepoint-performance-mistakes/)